# How to Receive Shopify store event on backend

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

How can I listen to Shopify store events to my backend?
like if I am adding any item to cart in this case my backend should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Via webhooks. In your case the `cart` webhooks.

You can read more about them here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook